# Move a row of data from one spreadsheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm new to the world of javascript & google apps script and I'm struggling to get a row of data to move from one spreadsheet to another. I have it moving a row from sheet to sheet within the same spreadsheet but not across spreadsheets.

I know I need to use `SpreadsheetApp.openById("insertID")` rather than `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` but I can't seem to make it work.

Here is the code I have that's working based on moving sheet to sheet, how do I modify it to move to a new spreadsheet?

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Timeline Submit" && r.getColumn() == 117 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("WIP");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target, {contentsOnly:true});
      } else if(s.getName() == "WIP" && r.getColumn() == 117 && r.getValue() == false) {
    var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Timeline Submit");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target, {contentsOnly:true});
      }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60080859/move-a-row-between-different-spreadsheets-google-spreadsheet/60083289#60083289)

Comment: You need to use an installable trigger.

Comment: Are you looking to move the row of data automatically each time a cell is edited in your source spreadsheet? Or by manually running the function from the editor (or with a UI menu button)? Also, be aware you need the target spreadsheet ID for what you want to do.

Comment: @AndresDuarte yes when a cell value is set to TRUE I want it to trigger the row to move to the new spreadsheet

Comment: Please provide an example/copy spreadsheet to understand what is the behavior you're looking for (in which sheet and row you want to copy the row, which is the source sheet, etc), removing the private information of course.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out everything in the second section of your code but it had too many errors so I just guessed and some of it.

Don't forget to go create a trigger for this in the Script Editor Edits/Current Project Triggers.

```
function installableOnEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="Timeline Submit" && e.range.columnStart==117 && e.value==true) {
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('id')
    var tsh= ss.getSheetByName("WIP");
    var trg=tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).copyTo(trg,{contentsOnly:true})
  }else if(sh.getName()=="WIP" && e.range.columnStart==17 && e.value==false) {
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('id')
    var tsh=ss.getSheetByName('Timeline Submit');
    var trg=sh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).copyTo(trg,{contentsOnly:true});
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper, unfortunately that code throws the error "Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 2, file "code")"

Comment: Your seem to me missing the event object.  I hope that you realize that it's not possible to run an onEdit function from the script editor.  It require the event object which it gets from the event trigger.  So I always debug these things while their live.

Comment: I'll try to elaborate a bit on Coopers answer. You face 2 problems:

1) Different code, which Cooper provided an example of
2) Access scope. For simple trigger onEdit, you cannot access other sheets or do many other fancy things like calling urlfetch, accessing drive,sending emails etc.
Because for this you need to grant app access to gmail account. And that's why you use installable trigger. It acts like ordinary onEdit trigger, but you have to install it manually using Script Editor Edits/Current Project Triggers, like Cooper mentioned.